Micrsoft Graph API to Power Pages Site
I have a scenario where I need to call Microsoft Graph API (for Microsoft booking) from Power Pages, without exposing access token in the JS. Is there a way I can in power pages / portal?

You can create an Azure Function that acts as a proxy between your Power Pages site and Microsoft Graph API. The function would securely handle the token generation and make the API calls on behalf of the portal. You can then call this Azure Function from Power Pages.

Hi Piyumi, Thanks for your reply. But I am looking for a direct approach, I could handle it in the power automate too, but the same problem exist in both which is exposing the service URL in JS.
